# Flutter - Blinking button

Tags: timer, dart, flutter

I need a call the user attention to a button. The first idea that came to mind is to add a blink animation. I really don't know how to do that, but I tried to make it work with the following code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  //basic logic to change the color variable here
  setState(() {});
});
```

It is straightforward, every second `setState` is called and the widget is created again.

But it doesn't work, the timer is called only once. And, besides that, calling `setState` within a `Timer` seems wrong to me.

There is a better approach to this?

Comment: Depending on your needs you may want to apply a `Curve` to Diego's answer

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can achieve this in an easy way using `AnimationController` and `FadeTransition` widget, here you have the code:

```
  class MyBlinkingButton extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyBlinkingButtonState createState() => _MyBlinkingButtonState();
  }

  class _MyBlinkingButtonState extends State<MyBlinkingButton>
      with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    AnimationController _animationController;

    @override
    void initState() {
      _animationController =
          new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
      _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: _animationController,
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () => null,
          child: Text("Text button"),
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _animationController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: MyBlinkingButton(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/54abca9c0ab8388be5ae42cc5d1ed9c5)

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much Diego.

Comment: Bad idea. Use `AnimatedWidget` or `AnimatedBuilder` instead of doing such `setState` call

Comment: This is perfect, but i'll mix it with the answer bellow for a more smooth result

Comment: Use SingleTickerProviderStateMixin instead of TickerProviderStateMixin as it is slightly more efficient in the case of the class only ever needing one Ticker. Here a single AnimationController was created during the lifetime of the class.

Comment: Can get a better effect by using `_animationController.repeat(reverse: true);`

Comment: Please add a gif to your answer. Answers which are related to design issues should consist gifs and screenshots.

Answer (score 13):

You can do that with this approach also.
My logic is a little different I am using alternate for animation. Once animation completed in forward I'm coming backward.

**Which is good for eyesight**

ie:

forward  -> backward

backward -> forward

and so on

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Wordpress App',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new BlinkAnimation(),
    );
  }
}

class BlinkAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlinkAnimationState createState() => _BlinkAnimationState();
}

class _BlinkAnimationState extends State<BlinkAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Color> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    final CurvedAnimation curve =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.linear);
    animation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.white, end: Colors.blue).animate(curve);
    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        controller.forward();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('Blink Animation'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animation,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
            return new Container(
              child: new RaisedButton(
                color: animation.value,
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.forward();
                },
                child: Text('Blink Animation'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your logic works great too. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Works good, I think it looks better with Curves.easeInOut instead of Curves.linear but maybe that's just a personal preference

Comment: Please add a gif to your answer. Answers which are related to design issues should consist gifs and screenshots.

Comment: @genericUser I just posted an answer with code from this answer updated to latest version, and with a gif demo :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example from [the answer by @nitishk72](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734013/2101117) but with code updated to null safety and more recent Flutter version.

#### Result:

[image: Flutter blinking text code example]

#### Code:

You can just copy this to [DartPad.dev](https://dartpad.dev) and it will work :)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Blink animation demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: BlinkAnimation(),
    );
  }
}

class BlinkAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlinkAnimationState createState() => _BlinkAnimationState();
}

class _BlinkAnimationState extends State<BlinkAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<Color?> animation;
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      vsync: this,
    );
    final CurvedAnimation curve =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.linear);
    animation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.white, end: Colors.blue).animate(curve);
    // Keep the animation going forever once it is started
    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      // Reverse the animation after it has been completed
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        controller.forward();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    // Remove this line if you want to start the animation later
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Blink Animation'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animation,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return Container(
              color: animation.value,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // Start the animation or do something else on click
                  // controller.forward();
                  print('button does something!');
                },
                child: const Text('Blink Animation'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Current answers are great but do not cover opacity blink (repeated fade in, fade out), you may use the following widget if that's your goal:

```
class BlinkAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const BlinkAnimation({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BlinkAnimation> createState() => _BlinkAnimationState();
}

class _BlinkAnimationState extends State<BlinkAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);
  late final Animation<double> animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: controller,
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: widget.child);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

based on [FadeTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeTransition-class.html)